# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Help me to solve this.

> 500 - An error has occurred.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY a.id desc LIMIT 20' at line 11 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

[image: Here the Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: 500 is server response, you should provide text version of SQL query

Comment: You have (at least) 3 errors in the SQL statements.  Yet you did not test for them, nor abort the web page with a user-friendly message, nor log more info in the error_log (or wherever).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide us text version of SQL query so that we can help you.

But i think your query has syntax error before "ORDER BY"